# iOS Text in label is hidden vertically

Tags: ios, xcode

I really don't know what is causing this, I added a label and when it is showing on the iPhone, it appears like this:

[image]

I'm really clueless on that one...

Comment: Check your title font size.

Comment: I have to reduce it really small in order for the text to appear. I tried to increase the label size with a larger font size but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto layout is messing with it. In Interface Builder, set the label's vertical content compression resistance priority to 1000.

Comment: Sorry, I don't always understand why auto layout makes the decisions it does. I know only how to tell it what's important to me.